# Android Kotlin: How do I successfully remove item from recyclerview, call notifyItemRangeChanged(), and animate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I'm trying to implement delete functionality. In order to get the correct positions of the itemViews, I call notifyItemRangeChanged() after deleting. However when I do that the cool animation of the itemView sliding to the right and being deleted is now gone. It looks like the notifyItemRangeChanged() cuts off the animation created by notifyItemRemoved(). Is there any way I can have the animation and the items delete properly?

Activity Code:

```
        circuitsObject?.circuits?.remove(circuitsObject?.circuits?.get(position))
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(position)
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, circuitsObject?.circuits!!.size)

        if (recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount!! == 0) {
            loadEmptyUI()
        }
```

Adapter Code:

```
class CircuitViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
...
itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener(circuit) }
itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
    onLongClickListener(position)
    true
}
```

The parameter "position" comes straight from the ViewHolder. To compensate for the fact that the position doesn't match the index of my data I am using "notifyItemRangeChanged". However, doing so gets rid of the animation. So I'm wondering if there's any way to bypass this such that I can still have the proper position logic as well as the animation for delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `notifyItemRangeChanged(...)` after calling `notifyItemRemoved(...)`.

Comment: If I don't call that then the ordering gets messed up. The retrieved position doesn't correspond to the same item in my data anymore. Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you show more code? My guess is that you are probably using the *position* parameter of *onBindViewHolder* method in your listeners. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: yes I am that is right. Let me try to edit some more code

Comment: try using viewHolder.layoutPosition instead of position in your listeners. That should fix the problem of position not matching index.

Comment: for some reason even after using holder.layoutPosition in place of position the index values are wrong and in some cases out of range.

Comment: Post a minimal reproducible example; it's really hard to find the cause of problem otherwise